# How to place random objects in a scattered way in corona without overlapping

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to display three different types of object on a same screen randomly, all the objects are created randomly but they are not scattered and sometimes overlap on each other, I want these random object to be far away from each other and must not overlap on each other.... Please give any suggestions... thanks

```
--first object to be displayed 5 times randomly on screen
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i=1, 5 do
local mrandom=math.random
local locx=mrandom(100,700)
local locy=mrandom(100,1140)
local obj1[i]=display.newImageRect('obj1.png',50,50)
obj1[i].x=locx
obj1[i].y=locy
--second object to be displayed 5 times randomly on screen
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i=1, 5 do
local mrandom=math.random
local locx2=mrandom(100,700)
local locy2=mrandom(100,1140)
local obj2[i]=display.newImageRect('obj2.png',50,50)
obj2[i].x=locx2
obj2[i].y=locy2
--third object to be displayed five times
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i=1, 5 do
local mrandom=math.random
local locx3=mrandom(100,700)
local locy3=mrandom(100,1140)
local obj3[i]=display.newImageRect('obj3.png',50,50)
obj3[i].x=locx3
obj3[i].y=locy3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a need to detect collisions with out physics:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/23/tutorial-non-physics-collision-detection/

Basically in your for loop once you generate your object, try to place it at your random x,y then loop over a table of your other objects seeing if your new object is colliding with one of the previous.  If so, regenerate the x and y and try again.

Comment: How we can stop object on the screen to touch other object without physics after generating random object like you said and retrieving the values over a tables.. thanks for your help

Comment: when you create the new object, loop over your table of existing objects and see if they are colliding.  If they are, generate a new random x, y until it no longer overlaps.